# Angular 2 Property does not exist on type 'CustomEvent'

Tags: angular

I am using the Final Release of Angular 2 and I have some code:

```
var passWidgetIdEvent = new CustomEvent("passWidgetIdEvent");
passWidgetIdEvent.widgetId = event.target.parentElement.id.replace("removeWidgetLink_", "");
document.dispatchEvent(passWidgetIdEvent);
```

That used to work, although now I am getting the red squigglies under the property `.widgetId` on `passWidgetIdEvent` and it says `Property 'widgetId' does not exist on type 'CustomEvent'`

I know that Angular 2 has @Output to emit events, but I need this event to be caught by regular javascript, outside of Angular 2.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `widgetId` property on `CustomEvent`. The TypeScript checker is absolutely right.

I think this should silence the checker

```
var passWidgetIdEvent = new CustomEvent("passWidgetIdEvent") as any;
passWidgetIdEvent.widgetId = event.target.parentElement.id.replace("removeWidgetLink_", "");
document.dispatchEvent(passWidgetIdEvent);
```

Comment: that second part worked like a charm! thank you so much

Comment: Glad to hear. Thanks for the feedback :)